# factorizing morphisms birationally to remove exceptional divisors

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Suppose $f:X \to Y$ is a surjective morphism with connected fibers between normal projective varieties, where $X$ is $\mathbb{Q}$-factorial (or even smooth). Suppose $E \subset X$ is the only $f$-exceptional divisor ($f$-exceptional means codim $f(E) \geq 2$) and that $f^{-1}f(E) = E$. Then by the universal property of blowing up, $f$ admits a factorization $ X \to Y^{'} \to Y $ where $Y^{'} \to Y$ is a birational morphism between normal projective varieties and $X \to Y^{'}$ has no exceptional divisors.

I was wondering if a similar factorization could be obtained without the assumption $f^{-1}f(E)=E$. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think I fully follow your argument, what exactly are you blowing up?  Blowing up $f(E)$ won't work in the way you claim it does (or are you just removing the indetermancies of $Y \to X$?)  But there are sort of variants where this is true.  By $E$ do you want it to have the reduced divisor structure?  Assuming there exists an $f$-ample anti-effective exceptional divisor $-E$, then there is a hope for this (I think that's ok in your setting).  Indeed, let $I_Z = f_* O_X(-nE)$ for some $n$ sufficiently divisible, then the blowup of $I_Z$ just recovers $X$.  I'm

Comment: In my case, $E$ is reduced, but $f$ is not birational, so there can't be any $f$-antiample effective divisor.  If $X$ is smooth, then it seems blowing up $f(E)$ works. If $X$ is only $\mathbb{Q}$-factorial, then we need to blow up an appropriate closed subscheme supported on $f(E)$.

Comment: Ah, it's not birational, sorry, I assumed it was.  But still, even if it's birational I don't understand your factorization: $X \to Y' \to Y$.  I assume $Y' \to Y$ is a blowup.  Are you asserting you can blow up the scheme theoretic image $f(E)$?

Comment: I am using the universal property of blow up as stated in Definition IV-16  (p-165) and Theorem IV-23 (p-170) of https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/b97680 .  Have I misunderstood it? Let me know your thoughts.

Comment: I still don't quite understand the blowup you are taking.  Ok, the example I have in mind is the following.  Take $Y = P^2$, let $X'' \to Y$ be obtained by blowing up a point.  Let $X' \to X'' \to Y$ blow up a point on the exceptional $E_1$.  Let $f : X \to Y$ be what you get when you contract the first exceptional (strict transform of $E_1$).  Then $X$ has one exceptional divisor $E$, $X$ is singular (though mildly).  However, there is no map from $X$ to the blowup of $f(E)$ (the blowup of $f(E)$ is just $X''$).  I imagine one can make this more annoying whem the relative dimension is higher.

Comment: In your case do you know something about the fibers of $f$?  (Or at least the generic one?  Is it Fano or close to?)